# Unity new Input System not registering Callbacks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, input

So I've been using Unity's Input System and it was working correctly until unfortunately it wasn't.
I didnt change any settings but all of a sudden the callbacks are not being registered anymore.
I tried resetting everything and just building it up from scratch but it still doesnt work.

Heres the steps I took:

1. Right-Click > Create > Input Actions
2. Open Input Actions editor, setup a new binding for an action.
3. Mark "Generate C# Class" checkbox.
4. input.cs is created, in Scripts Folder.
5. New script which uses input.cs to receive callbacks and perform actions when input is received from the player:

   ```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

    public class MouseControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Input input;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            input = new Input();
            input.Player.Enable();

            lastPosition = this.transform.position;

            input.Player.MoveCamera.performed += DragCamera;
            print("Inputs enabled: " + input.Player.enabled); //Prints true at start of Game.
        }



    void DragCamera(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
    {
    print("StartedDragCamera");
    if (!Mouse.current.leftButton.isPressed)
    {
        dragging = false;
        return;
    }

    //create plane to raycast to
    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());

    if (plane.Raycast(ray, out float distance))
    {
        if (Mouse.current.leftButton.wasPressedThisFrame)
        {
            startDrag = ray.GetPoint(distance);
            dragging = true;
        }
        else
            targetPosition += startDrag - ray.GetPoint(distance);
    }
    }
   ```

As soon as the key is pressed, the `DragCamera()` method should run, and the "Started Dragging" should show up in the console, but it doesnt.
I tried just binding it to the leftMouse butoon on the Mouse to see if it worked but unfortunately it doesnt work either.

The weirdest thing is that I had it working for an hour with no issues and then all of a sudden it stopped registering the inputs.
I turned off all UI and everything else so its just an empty scene to test this.
There is no UI Input Modules active either that could be interfering.

The Action Map is setup properly in the editor so I only have a LeftBUtton on Mouse binding that should send a callback to all subsribed methods(only DragCamera in this case).

Thanks

Comment: Ive been trying to figure this out for atleast 3hours now, and literally 5 minutes after I make this post the script automagically starts working as intended again. The only thing I did was add a Player Input Module in the Editor, then I deactivated it for some reason, because i knew it doesnt do anything maybe, and I put in my action Map 'Input', just wanted to try one more time so I ran it and voila... but now I have no idea why this worked and I had to think back and this is the only thing I did. before it didnt work now it does. wat the hell unity